# Calculating the KL divergence term for VAE loss

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, torch, loss-function

I am interested in calculating the KL divergence term for a VAE loss function.

I have seen many examples using some facsimile of the [following keras code](https://jaketae.github.io/study/vae/):

```
kl_loss = -0.5 * K.sum(1 + z_log_var - K.square(z_mean) - K.exp(z_log_var), axis=-1)
```

However, I have also found another method (which uses the torch library) of calculating the KL divergence, as shown by [this code (I'll call this the latter example):](https://github.com/Michedev/VAE_anomaly_detection/blob/master/vae_anomaly_detection/VAE.py)

```
kl = kl_divergence(pred_result['latent_dist'], Normal(0,1).mean(dim=0).sum()
```

In the latter example, `pred_result['latent_dist']` is distribution object describing normal distributions parameterised by two layers: mean and st_dev (not log_var, in this case).

`Normal(0,1)` is also a distribution object, representing a normal distribution with mean = 0 and standard deviation = 1.

My question is this: Is the latter example a legitimate/correct way of calculating the KL divergence term for a VAE?

Comment: No, in the code you linked `pred_result['latent_dist']` are distribution objects, not samples. Note that questions on this site should ideally be self-contained without external links.

Comment: You are correct, I have made corresponding edits.